# Proof Verification: Group Theory (Exponent Properties)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, exponentiation

Can anyone please verify this proof:

Prove that $(g^m)^n = (g)^{mn}$

Proof: $(g^m)^n = \underbrace{g^m*g^m....*g^m}_{\text{n times}}$

$= \underbrace{[\underbrace{(g*g*g...*g)}_{\text{m times}}*\underbrace{(g*g*g...*g)}_{\text{m times}}....\underbrace{(g*g*g...*g)]}_{\text{m times}}}_{\text{n times}}$

Then this is $m$ $g's$ $n$ times

$= g^{mn}$

Does this proof work?
If not, then what alternative proof is there?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the basic idea, yes. You might want to write it out as an induction proof, as an exercise. That's the usual way of taking "$\cdots$" out of proofs.

In this case, it's clear that $(g^{m})^1=g^{m\cdot 1}$ (because both expressions are simply equal to $g^m$). So you can assume that, for some $n$, we have $(g^m)^n=g^{mn}$, and then use that to show that $(g^m)^{n+1}=g^{m(n+1)}$. You'll want to use a theorem telling you that $g^ag^b=g^{a+b}$. Have you got that available?

Comment: Yes, already proved that $g^ag^b=g^{a+b}$ . Can you elaborate on  how $(g^m)^1 = g^{m.1}$ is obvious? How can we just assume that if the generalisation of that is eventually what are looking to prove?

Comment: It follows from the fact that anything to the power $1$ equals itself, and that the product of integers $m\times 1=m$.

Comment: Also, since we've proved that $g^ag^b=g^{a+b}$, we can then say that $(g^m)^{n+1}=(g^m)^n * (g^m)$  and then $(g^m)^{n+1}=(g^{mn}) * (g^m)$ (by induction step) and then $(g^{mn}) * (g^m) = g^{mn+m}$ from $g^ag^b=g^{a+b}$, is this correct?

Comment: Then you can use your other result, and say that $(g^{mn})({g^m})=g^{mn+m}$. Simplifying that last exponent will get you what you need.

Comment: Thanks! Just realised that.